# How come I can't run VboxWindowsadditions.exe on my Virtual Box Version 7.0.8 r156879 (Qt5.15.2) Ubuntus

Tags: virtualbox

Guys I'm a newbie to Ubuntus. I'm attempting to enable guest additions on my virtual machine so I can paste from the host to virtual machine VirtualBox and vice versa. On the virtual machine under My computer or vbox_GAs_7.0.8 I have 3 VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe files and when I attempt to run them I get an error message as seen below. How do I resolve this?[image]

Also, I attempted to update the same files and got the following error message. I've rebooted the guest (virtualbox) machine and it didn't make a difference.
[image]

Comment: Is the VM Windows or Linux?  If the VM is not Windows, you can't run .exe files there is likely another installer script there that is more like a `.run` or `.sh` and not a .exe that you'd run for a Linux guest system

Comment: The VM is Linux and I'm not sure where I'd go to find this installer script. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your image, you have the ISO and mounted it in the VM.  That's good!

The version to run is *NOT* the `.exe` though, it's the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` file.  Execute that file and let it install and you'll have VBox Additions installed.  There is no guarantee however that all functions that Windows has will work on Linux, though the vast majority should work.

Comment: thanks I'll look into running this file. Thanks man

Comment: Thomas Ward thanks for your help and just like you said. The solution was to run the command sudo bash LinuxAdditions.run let it finish and then the command reboot which reboots the VM. Thanks man for your help.

Comment: @user2727050 Glad it helped!  Mark the answer as accepted and the question solved with the check mark on my answer to make sure the system reflects the solved status :)

Comment: Thomas Ward hey man just saw this today and just hit the check mark. Again thank you so much for your help. I greatly appreciate it